# .net core injection Factory

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, factory

I am trying to make a factory in net Core. And completely get stacked.

How to make factory pattern using Microsoft Dependency Injection library for .net core?

Any hints?

Comment: Any [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44793349/4335854

DI is done through the ServiceCollection where you can only have one implementation per interface so doing a factory pattern directly on the service collection may not work because it does not support dynamic creation of the interface implementation.

What I did in my answer is created an injectable implementation of a factory that may meet the same requirements as a factory of injectable implementations